# Is it possible to get Dash-Cytoscape graph tooltips?

Tags: python, plotly-dash, cytoscape

Here is an example cytoscape graph that I created using this site as reference [here](https://dash.plotly.com/cytoscape/elements)

[image]

I was wondering if its possible to show the tooltips when hovering on each node in a graph in the same way that plotly can do to its graphs ([like this](https://dash.plotly.com/interactive-graphing))

Comment: I'm interested in that too!

Answer (score 3):

Dash Cytoscape does not have a built-in tooltip. It's possible to use hover callbacks (documented in the [event callback guide](https://dash.plotly.com/cytoscape/events)) to update the content of a separate component (such as a `html.P` on the side). However that will not behave the same way as a tooltip.

You might also be able to build a custom component (using the [component boilerplate](https://github.com/plotly/dash-component-boilerplate)) that follows your cursor and display custom information (given by the `hoverData` prop) whenever it is updated by a hover callback. However, that would require knowledge of JavaScript and React, which can be learned from the [React for Python developers primer](https://dash.plotly.com/react-for-python-developers).